# How to TAB to auto-complete with org-mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, emacs-prelude

I've installed `auto-complete-mode`, and I'm using org-mode. When I hit TAB to auto-complete words, it instead tries to indent the line. Sometimes it indents the whole paragraph, sometimes it does nothing.

I tried customizing the variable `(setq tab-always-indent 'complete)` and changing it to nil, but now when I hit TAB, it just inserts tab spaces across the screen.

I know it's possible to successfully use org-mode with yasnippet and auto-complete both working correctly, because with [Emacs Live](https://github.com/overtone/emacs-live) it works out of the box.

Comment: Did you try this: (ac-flyspell-workaround)

Answer (score 11):

Auto-complete uses the variable [ac-modes](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/manual.html#ac-modes) to decide whether to enable auto-completion in a particular mode, by default `org-mode` is not present in this list. So to enable auto-completion in `org-mode` simply add it to the `ac-modes` something like this should work

```
(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'org-mode)
```

Also to complete using <kbd>tab</kbd> you will need to set `ac-trigger-key` to <kbd>tab</kbd> like so (link to the [manual](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/manual.html#Trigger_Key))

```
(ac-set-trigger-key "TAB")
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately that doesn't work. Auto-complete-mode is on, displaying the `AC` in the mode line. I can trigger completion by doing `M-x auto-complete`, but TAB still has no effect.

Comment: What does `C-h k` `tab` give? Does it give something like `TAB (translated from <tab>) runs the command ac-trigger-key-command,`

Comment: <tab> runs the command org-cycle, which is an interactive autoloaded
Lisp function in `org.el'.

Comment: Oh right! How can I forget that `org-mode` takes the `tab` key, you can get auto-completion in `org-mode` by overriding `tab` key but I would advice NOT to do so since `tab` is very useful key in `org-mode`. You can bind auto-complete to some other key if you want.

Comment: Hmm, in Emacs Live (another curated Emacs package), TAB to auto-complete does work in org-mode. (And TAB to org-cycle also works, depending on whether you're on a headline or not.)

Comment: @PeterSalazar, just checked `emacs-live` it does prompt me for completion with `tab` rather it pops up completion immediately (i.e. without pressing `tab`). Maybe you have a function declared somewhere that is making `tab` work for you in org-mode. Just do `C-h k` `tab` (in your emacs-live), you will come to know the command run by `tab`, this will also provide a link to the function's source you can copy that to your init file. I will also try to post a function that will achieve what you want but I am not sure that is a good a idea.

Comment: Emacs Live: <tab> runs the command yas-expand, which is an alias for
`yas-expand-from-trigger-key' in `yasnippet.el'.

It is bound to <tab>, <menu-bar> <YASnippet> <Expand trigger>.

(yas-expand &optional FIELD)

Expand a snippet before point. If no snippet
expansion is possible, call command `org-cycle'.

Optional argument FIELD is for non-interactive use and is an
object satisfying `yas--field-p' to restrict the expansion to.

Comment: Hi @PeterSalazar, I guess you are looking for the yasnippet package available, at https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet. Emacs live is running the command from yasnippet it is not autocompleting

Comment: It is autocompleting. There are only a handful of snippets defined in the snippets package, but in Emacs Live org-mode, TAB autocompletes any word that already appears in the buffer.

Comment: `TAB` is not auto-completing for me (in emacs-live). I looked at emacs-live's auto-complete configuration they do not seem to be doing anything that will enable tab completion. Just try adding `(setq ac-auto-start 2)` and `(add-to-list 'ac-sources ac-source-words-in-buffer)` in your init file.

Comment: I just did a clean install of Emacs Live, and for me it works out of the box. Launch Emacs, then in that initial default scratch buffer, `M-x org-mode`. Then type the first two letters of one of the words in the welcome phrase, then `TAB`. For me it autocompletes.

Comment: @PeterSalazar after the menu appears, do `C-g` and then press `tab` again does it auto-complete? What you are seeing is a side-effect of `(setq ac-auto-start 2)` which start auto-completion as soon as you type 2 chars.

Comment: Well, on my emacs `(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'org-mode)` causes an error on startup, because the definition of `'ac-modes` is void, so no adding to that.

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was to install [`org-ac`](https://github.com/aki2o/org-ac) from melpa-stable. This caused Emacs to show the completed word after the cursor, as if I had already typed it, but in a different color. Using <kbd>Tab</kbd> accepts that completion.

(Emacs: `GNU Emacs 24.5.1`)

Answer (score 0):

The only robust solution I found was to disable flyspell mode <kbd>M-x</kbd>`flyspell-mode` when I want to use auto-completion in org-mode: Emacs 26.1, GTK+ 3.22.30, Org mode version 9.1.14, Spacemacs 0.200.13. The suggestion `(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'org-mode)` did not work and I was unable to find `ac-flyspell-workaround`. Because completion in org-mode is more valuable to me than is flyspell mode, I turn off flyspell much of the time.